PS E:\wsl> wsl The system cannot find the specified path Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/CreateVm/HCS/ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND
I am using the wsl in the windows.But,when i type the wsl,i get the error message mentioned follow.
I hope to start WSL on Windows system.But i get this:
PS E:\wsl> wsl The system cannot find the specified path  
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/CreateVm/HCS/ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Is wsl already installed in the system?
